# Find_if function in vector

Tags: c++, stl, visual-c++

Is this function sort the given vector array ?

Give your suggestions please

Regards,

vasantham

Comment: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find_if.html

Comment: you want to sort or you want to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find_if is an function of an  and returns an iterator to the first element in the range.

```
   #include <list>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <iostream>

  bool greater10 ( int value )
  {
  if(value == 10)
   {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  }

 int main( )
  {
       using namespace std;

       list <int> L;
       list <int>::iterator Iter;
      list <int>::iterator result;

      L.push_back( 10 );
      L.push_back( 9 );
      L.push_back( 15 );
      L.push_back( 8);
      L.push_back( 10 );

     cout << "L = ( " ;
      for ( Iter = L.begin( ) ; Iter != L.end( ) ; Iter++ )
          cout << *Iter << " ";
      cout << ")" << endl;


      result = find_if( L.begin( ), L.end( ), &greater10 );
      for( ;result != L.end(); result++ )
       {
      cout << *result <<"\t";
         cout <<endl;
      }
  }
```

This function returns the first element as iterator and it willnot sort the vector array.

Answer (score 3):

`std::find_if` isn't a member of vector, it's a free function template from `<algorithm>`.

It doesn't sort the range it is given, it just returns an iterator to the first element of the given range for which the given predicate returns `true`.